# LLVM: make a Global Variable linkage type as linkonce

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am working on the llvm compiler to generate a C code.

I am have the following code in the compiler that declares a global variable in my C code:

```
GlobalVariable* gvar_int64_test = new GlobalVariable(M, 
    IntegerType::get(M.getContext(), 64),
    false,
    GlobalValue::LinkOnceAnyLinkage,
    0,
    "test");
```

The compiler runs parallel to compile several piece of C files. But I would want all the global variable of the name 'test' in all the compiled file to share the same value or address. So I figure that maybe setting it to 'LinkOnceAnyLinkage' for the linkage type might work.

However, when running the passes. it says:

```
invalid linkage type for global declaration
i64* @test
```

Changing it to ExternalLinkage would not raise this issue but I do need it to have the linkonce property.

I was wondering what could be the issue?

Thank you all for the potential help

Answer (score -1):

Where are you putting this?  In a .h file?  I really don't understand what you mean by the linkage thing [or why you would want/need it]

Assuming this is in a file, such as `myheader.h`, what you need is something like:

```
#ifdef DEFINE_GLOBAL
GlobalVariable* gvar_int64_test = what you specified ...
#else
extern GlobalVariable* gvar_int64_test;
#endif
```

Before the `#include` for your .h, in one and *only* one .cpp file do:

```
#define DEFINE_GLOBAL
#include <myheader.h>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am actually putting the above code in the llvm compiler. And it would not work to put that in a header file since by doing that thousands of other C files are required to be modified.

Comment: @user3761728 Still not getting it [and I've been doing C for 35+].  Can you post more code to illustrate.  Do you mean that your original construct is done by thousands of files?  That is, there are many such `gvar_*` scattered?  BTW, I have many perl scripts to change "thousands of C files" if necessary--do it all the time.  If your def is not in a .h, why any conflict?  Can you post _two_ or more files that clearly show the conflict, possibly with a little extra stuff?